# Retrieve ID of AD security group

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, sharepoint-framework

Can you please tell me how can i retrieve the ID of a security group, so i can add this value to a listItem field of type USER

i have this values when a search for a security group by name.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can using PowerShell command to retrieve security groups ID :

$groupid = Get-MsolGroup | Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -eq “**Test Security Group**”}

$groupid

About how to use SharePoint online PowerShell ，you can reference :

https://howtodowithsharepoint.wordpress.com/2015/12/19/office-365-how-to-configure-powershell-for-o365/